# Gravitational brehmsstralung

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves

I have read this pdf, and its 5th paragraph, where it talks about gravitational brehmsstralung.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243311274_Gravitons_in_Minkowski_space-time_Interactions_and_results_of_astrophysical_interest

It says that it is only possible for not too soft gravitons. It talks about this effect from the Sun too.

I think gravitons are still theoretical but this pdf is talking about gravitational brehmsstralung like it has already been measured.

I am not able to find from this if this is possible to check by detecting Gravitational Waves. GWs have already been detected so maybe gravitational brehmsstralung has been detected too?

1. Is there such an effect as gravitational brehmsstralung?
2. Have there been any experiments to check this, and does this work by detecting GWs?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Consider to provide a permalink to prevent link rot.

Comment: @Qmechanic can you please help me how to do that?

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(77)90006-0